# How to publish a campaign on Facebook Manager?

Tags: json, facebook, helper

I want to publish a campaign on facebook via Facebook Manager or Business and everything's fine but at the very end I have this error:

> Invalid Page Welcome Message for Messenger Ads: The message text (page_welcome_message) is not valid for ads with Messenger as the destination.

I don't know what to do, I have tried everything but no result.

The only thing I know is that is from JSON, might be an error in the script from Facebook ?

Comment: On the internet, I advocate not using begging language intended to make readers feel pity for you. This includes "please help me" and sad-face emoticons. It is healthy for you to have a positive frame of mind, and believe you are able to do this, rather than allowing yourself to slip into helplessness. [Related reading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem's solution

### https://jocespot.wordpress.com/2017/09/20/manychat-facebook-ads-error-the-message-text-page_welcome_message-is-invalid-solution/

### [image]